# Django crispy forms not adding id to field

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to add a class to a field in my form. When I check the rendered template, it is missing the class i have added.

form:

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper, Layout
from crispy_forms.layout import Field

class OperationsCalendarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('start', css_class="datetimepicker")
        )

        super(OperationsCalendarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = OperationsCalendar
        exclude = ('creation', 'last_modified')
```

form.html

```
{{ form|crispy }}
```

I get:

```
<input class="dateinput form-control" id="id_start" name="start" type="text">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `FormHelper`, you need to use this tag in template`{% crispy form %}` instead of this `{{ form|crispy }}`. And you need to register all fields in `Layout`, like you did with `start`. If you want to see it all, sure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. `{% crispy operations_calendar_form %}` gives me 'VariableDoesNotExist'. {% crispy form %} does give me the one field though. Is it possible to add all the fields without the need to reference them in my forms.py

Comment: `{% crispy operations_calendar_form %}` yes sory, here I mean, your form name in view, as I see it  just `form`. If you want to see all fields, you need to register it in `Layout`, like you did with `start` field